# LDAP search using distinguishedName

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I know the answer is probably no, however, I figured before I give up I may as well ask.
Is it possible to find all objects in OU using distinguishedName, let say I need to find all objects in OU which is called Groups, i try to use something like this, but it dosn't work

```
(DN=*OU=Groups,OU=Corp-Users,DC=fabrikam,DC=internal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ldapsearch -s one -h ldaphost -b "OU=Groups,OU=Corp-Users,DC=fabrikam,DC=internal" "objectclass=*" dn` to get all nodes of the level *OU=Groups,OU=Corp-Users,DC=fabrikam,DC=internal*. Replace the `-s one` with `-s sub` to get all subentries as well.

**What does it do?**

It uses `OU=Groups,OU=Corp-Users,DC=fabrikam,DC=internal` as the search base (**-b**) and searches just on that level (**-s one**) or on all sublevels (**-s sub**) all nodes that have an attribute `objectclass` set (which should be **every** node!)

The rest is just syntactical stuff that might be needed like setting the LDAP-Host (**-h ldaphost**) or just returning the dn (the **dn** right at the end)

I'm not sure what the command for windows is though.